# How to get data from database in time range if it's not contained before the time range?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table that contains some data like:

- Product ID
- Operation
- Date
- Result (OK or NOK).

I'd like to set a time range. In that time range I'd like to get the first Result of all Product ID by Date.

After that I'd like to check the whole table (out of the time range too), if there is an earlier test Result of those PID-Operation-Result "pack" what I got from the selected time range. How should I do that?

Comment: Usually it is a good practice to include some code showing what you have tried yourself so far. Also include exact database software version (like SQL Server 2008, MySQL ...). It is also unclear, why you have used C# tag.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to select one record for each PID, the oldest. But if it's not in the time range you want all results, even if there are multiple for one ID? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this query

```scala
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE Date Between '01/01/2016' and '10/06/2016'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to select one record for each PID, the oldest. But if it's not in the time range you want all results, even if there are multiple for one ID? Is that correct?

Presuming you're using SQL-Server you could use a ranking function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [Product ID],
           [Operation],
           [Date],
           [Result],
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Product ID] ORDER BY [Date])
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT [Product ID], [Operation], [Date], [Result]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1 OR [Date] NOT BETWEEN @BeginRange AND @EndRange
```

Comment: I'd like to get the results from the selected time range. But those PID-s which I get from this, could be tested earlier than the selected time range. In that case I would like to get the test result and time which is out of the selected range (the oldest).